# Libgdx - Actions; adding one action to multiple actors

Tags: android, action, libgdx, actor

I have defined a set of actions and I am trying to add that into multiple actors. Here's the code:

```
        ParallelAction actions = new ParallelAction();

        RotateByAction rotateAction = new RotateByAction();
        rotateAction.setAmount(rotationAmount);

        ScaleByAction scaleAction = new ScaleByAction();
        scaleAction.setAmount(-0.01f);

        DelayAction delayAction = new DelayAction();
        delayAction.setDuration(0.05f);

        RepeatAction rAction = new RepeatAction();
        rAction.setCount(100);

        actions.addAction(rotateAction);
        actions.addAction(scaleAction);
        actions.addAction(delayAction);
        rAction.setAction(actions);



        for(Monster mon : mons) // mons is ArrayList of type Monster (which extends Image)
            mon.addAction(rAction);
```

But the above logic just adds action to the last actor in my ArrayList. 
Why can't I use the same action with multiple actors? Do i need to define as many actions as actors, or is there any other way to do it?

I looked upon Pool here https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d I don't seem to get a hold of it. Is it useful for my problem? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because all Actors do habe the reference to one Sequence. So every Actor that does have the sequence do the same. For example if You use 1 Sprite for 10 actors and you do change it in 1 actor every other actor does have the changing too. So if you add a sequence to 10 actors it does get speed up by 10 times because every `.act()` from an actors does update the sequence **(because inside of every actor.act it does update all Actions by the delta time!)**. So you do update the sequence with every actor thats why it does not work. You need to create  a new squence for every actor thats right.
Simply change your code to this:

```
for(Monster mon : mons){ // mons is ArrayList of type Monster (which extends Image)
        RotateByAction rotateAction = new RotateByAction();
        rotateAction.setAmount(rotationAmount);

        ScaleByAction scaleAction = new ScaleByAction();
        scaleAction.setAmount(-0.01f);

        DelayAction delayAction = new DelayAction();
        delayAction.setDuration(0.05f);

        RepeatAction rAction = new RepeatAction();
        rAction.setCount(100);

        actions.addAction(rotateAction);
        actions.addAction(scaleAction);
        actions.addAction(delayAction);
        rAction.setAction(actions);
        mon.addAction(rAction); 
}
```

This may does take longer at the init but it should correct your bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, does this problem comes only with the SequenceAction or is it true for all problems?

Comment: it should be true for all problems! As i said in every regular `act()` of an Actor you do update the Actions by the delta time. And if they do have the same Action you do update the Action multiple times. So it should be for all actions!